# Is there a way to move files marked as spam to another folder in Evolution?

Tags: filter, evolution

The "Junk" folder in evolution is not an actual folder, as all of the messages marked as junk are still in the Inbox on imap. There is a filter option in Evolution based on whether or not a message has been flagged, and I set one up to move any emails flagged as junk into an actual subfolder. The reason is that I get my emails both on my phone and on my desktop, and while having them visually separated on my desktop is nice my phone remains inundated with spam emails. The filter itself never gets triggered though, even if I select all of the junk emails and choose Apply Filters. The filter condition is Junk Test -> Message is junk, and the action is to move it to a folder I created. Why would this not be working?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Tried to access mail from my new smartphone.
Also tried to set up a filter, but that did not work since mail in the inbox is still spam-filtered in to a virtual folder.

Well I am fortunate that my provider (1&1) allows to configure spam filtering
on the server side. I changed the configuration to the option where spam is spam filtered and moved to a special imap spam folder, where I still have the opportunity to inspect them for false positives.
Now, here is an idea, if you are not that fortunate: (I am still running an older version of evolution, though, 2.28)

- Go to preferences and uncheck the option to spam filter in the inbox.
- Set up a filter that on condition that status is spam will move the mail in question to a special spam folder.

I have tested this and the spam filter runs on the mail in question!